How to add exception to ignored common directories?
I'm excluding several paths from subdirectories in git, but sometimes I want certain files to be included.
the project tree is
.
├── D
│   └── DukeNukem
│       └── drive_c
├── W
│   ├── WingCommander1rev1-1990
│   │   └── drive_c
│   ├── WingCommander2-1991
│   │   └── drive_c
│   ├── WingCommanderAcademy-1993
│   │   └── drive_c
│   └── WingCommanderArmada-1993
│       └── drive_c
...

I want the contents of all drive_[a-z] directories to be ignored. Unless there are specific files that should be included.
For this I have the base gitignore:
# project root /.gitignore
!**/drive_c/
**/drive_c/*

(using drive_?/, but keeping simpler here. i fails with both patterns.)
Now if I want to include /W/WingCommanderArmada-1993/drive_c/WC2.CFG i tried

adding gitignore to the directory with !drive_c/WC2.CFG
adding exception to main gitignore with !/W/WingCommanderArmada-1993/drive_c/WC2.CFG
using drive_c/* as the question bellow suggests doesn't block the dirs, i had to use **/drive_c/* maybe this is the problem?

I believe the answer is in .gitignore exclude folder but include specific subfolder but I cannot construct a solution using the information there.
the repo is public
A workaround that is almost working is to set fixed levels.
# main .gitignore
!/*/*/drive_c/
/*/*/drive_c/*

but even then i can't add files back from .gitignores in the leaf dirs, such as bellow. both lines fail. But adding the full path one to the root gitignore works.
# /W/WingCommanderArmada-1993/.gitignore
!/W/WingCommanderArmada-1993/drive_c/WC2.CFG
!./drive_c/WC2.CFG

